# Why does [appium-*] exist?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

It seems to me like questions currently tagged with [appium-*] should instead be tagged with [appium] and [*] separately (excluding [appium-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appium-desktop) as it is a separate GUI for Appenium). This includes

- [appium-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appium-android) should be [appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appium) & [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- [appium-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appium-ios) should be [appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appium) & [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)
- [appium-snackbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appium-snackbar) should be [appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appium) & [snackbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snackbar)

I am no expert on the matter so please educate me if this is nonsensical, but I think it would be in line with the tag-system we have in place. Imagine we would create a tag of every use case of every technology or software. For example instead of having questions with [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) we would have [json-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-javascript), [json-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-java), [json-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-python) and so on. This would incredibly bloat the number of necessary tags.

Another hint that these tags should be collapsed into one is the fact the tag wiki of all tags is identical (if it exists). I would, therefore, suggest a retag as detailed above and a subsequent synonymization of all tags with [appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appium).

Comment: Why? If you're proposing a change you need to explain why you think your way is better.

Comment: @RobertLongson Understandable. Added an explanation

Comment: Given that the [tag:appium-android] tag wiki is even written in a way that applies to all platforms supported by Appium, this request seems to make a lot of sense.